# Can't save custom data to "sales_order" table

Tags: database, sales, ce-1.4.0.1

I'm running Mage 1.4.0.1.

With a mysql setup script, I have created a new column "asyncupload_validated" (tinyint(1) not null default 0) to the "sales_order" table.

I try to set this data to 1 and save it.

Here is my code, who doesn't work currently :

```
$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($_POST["order_id"]);
$order->setAsyncuploadValidated(1);
$order->save(); 
echo "<p>".$this->__("Your files are now validated.")."</p>";
```

The code is called (tested with some Mage::log) and the POST var is ok. It seems to be the save() param who is failing.

Comment: Try clearing the cache. Even if your cache is disabled the table describe results are still cached by ZF.

Comment: I've just cleared the cache, it's not the problem. Maybe something with a mapping or the large amount of Magento tables related to orders ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my late reply, i've been working on Magento upgrade.
Now I'm running 1.6.2, the easiest version with our custom modules.

I've solved my problem by using the addAttribute method.

See documentation here : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378394/magento-adding-a-new-column-to-sales-flat-quote-item-and-sales-flat-order-item)

Answer (score 0):

I would say in version 1.4 (UPDATE!!! REALLY!!!) orders where still eav, so to add a table you should use `Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup` to `addAttribute()`. If you want it in the sales_order table, just use as `type` `static`.

If the attribute is added and the Zend_Db cache is renewed it should be saved.

Comment: 1.4 was the version that introduced sales_flat_order tables - 1.4.1 introduced sales_flat_order_grid

Comment: really? I thought it was 1.6 but then in 1.6 came Resource vs Mysql4? But still,adding the attribute with `addAttribute` works for me :)